# Populate Pandas Dataframe Based on Column Values Matching Other Column Names

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'd like to populate one dataframe (df2) based on the column names of df2 matching values within a column in another dataframe (df2).  Here is a simplified example:

```
names = list('abcd')

data = list('aadc')

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['data']) 
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.empty([4,4]),columns=names)

df1:

    data
0   a
1   a
2   d
3   c

df2:

      a       b       c       d
0   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
1   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
2   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
3   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
```

I'd like to update df2 so that the first row returns a number (let's say 1 for now) under column a, and 0 for other columns.  Second row of df2 would return the same, third frow would return a 0 for column a/b/c and a 1 for column d, fourth row would return a 0 for column a/b/d and a 1 for column c.

Thanks very much for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can do numpy broadcasting here:

```
df2[:] = (df1['data'].values[:,None] == df2.columns.values).astype(int)
```

Or use `get_dummies`:

```
df2[:] = pd.get_dummies(df1['data']).reindex(df2.columns, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   a  b  c  d
0  1  0  0  0
1  1  0  0  0
2  0  0  0  1
3  0  0  1  0
```

Comment: Thank you! I realized I left off part of what I am trying to do, but this gets me halfway there.  Instead of replacing the values with 1, I actually need to replace the values with a unique value per index.  Basically, if df1 had one more column with a unique value in each cell, I would need that value in df2, instead of a static 1.